# pywinauto - testing file icon overlays

Tags: file, icons, overlay, pywinauto, pyautogui

I am looking for a good method for testing icon overlays of a file.

For example, Dropbox has different icon overlays for synced/syncing files etc.

I am currently using pyautogui's locateOnScreen() function, with a dictionary containing screenshots of all icon overlays types.

But using this approach, I need to have screenshots for every OS(different resolution, UI) and also tests are a little unstable.

NOTE: The tests will be cross platform(Mac and Windows)

Is there any other method besides image recognition that can be used for testing file icon overlays?

Comment: Do you need cross-platform or Windows only approach?

Comment: Yes, I the tests will run on Mac and Windows. I've also updated the original post with this detail